# Disable eth0 for the current session

Tags: networking, terminal

Is there a way to disconnect eth0 (wired connection) for just until I reboot? Or even a way to just bring it down then up again before I shut the computer down? I want to do this because sometimes I want to be on Wi-Fi and when the signal gets low, it hops back to eth0, even if I manually disconnected from it. Using Ubuntu MATE 15.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this could work

To disable eth0:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
```

To enable eth0:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Comment: I tried this before but I guess once I disconnect from the network it worked. It didn't do this before but I was connected to eth0 at the time.